# Specifying a GeoTools read-only DataSource

Tags: datasource, shapefile, geotools

Using a call such as:

DataStore dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(map);

Is there an entry I can make to the map to make the datastore read-only? The only thing I have seen is the URL to specify the name for the datasource.

I imagine that the reason a map is used to send in arguments is that various data sources require different parameters. I am dealing with shape files right now and have not seen any way to specify it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A [DataStore](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/data/datastore.html) doesn't have a notion of being read-only or read-write.  On the other hand, the classes which access a feature type do; there is a difference between a FeatureSource and a FeatureStore.  The former class does not have any write/update functions.  A high-level description is [here](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/data/featuresource.html).

By default `datastore.getFeatureSource` returns its result cast as a `FeatureSource` (read-only).  If you want to have write-access, you have to try and cast the `FeatureSource` to a `FeatureStore`.  As a note, not all DataStore implementations provide write-access.